# I can't upload some pictures with PHP

Tags: php, image, file, uploading

I made a PHP aplication that can upload pictures to the server. It is working fine most of the time but it won't upload some pictures.

Here you can download all files including one picture that does work and one that does not: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwoIBS8cNsz4Rjl0eERMb2FndUk/view?usp=sharing

Here is my PHP code (file name: upload.php):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $target_dir = "slike/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if file already exists
        if (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check file size
        if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
            echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Allow certain file formats
        if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
        // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
            } else {
                echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }

?>
```

Here is my HTML code (file name: index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Wamp server on Windows 8 and i didn't change any configuration.

(English is not my native language and I hope to get more answers about the code as grammatical corrections.)

Comment: put debug statements in your code at key points to see what is happening with the files that won't upload

Comment: _"It is working fine most of the time but it won't upload some pictures."_ Any errors when it fails to upload? Is there anything different between the images that will upload and those who won't?

Comment: Probably you should change the value of 'upload_max_filesize' and 'post_max_size' in php.ini. Try to put a bigger value for this and try again.

Comment: @TismonVarghese that's it :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000)` - (5000000/1024*2) limit is 4.7 MB

this one dont work.jpg : error => `Upload ImageFile is an image - image/jpeg.Sorry, your file is too large.Sorry, your file was not uploaded.` image size around 8 Mb

change `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000` to something higher

Comment: It doesn't help :( . It looks like the first IF is not true some times.

Comment: its because of your file size change 5000000 to 500000000 and try again

Answer (score -1):

I know this response is a little overdue. But for anyone else who might experience a similar error. I recently experienced a similar problem.  So I changed the 5000000(which is in decimal) to 5242880(which is in binary), and it worked like MAGIC.